# How to connect two networks in NEURON software?

Tags: neuroscience, theoretical-neuroscience, computational-modeling, neural-network

So my goal is to connect STN and SNc neurons by giving synaptic weights and then see the response. I have already modelled STN and SNc separately and observed their response.
 I need help with the coding part. I have already done this in MATLAB, but am supposed to do everything in NEURON simulator, by creating mod and hoc files. I went through some of the codes in modeldb website, but those seem way too complicated.

Comment: Welcome to CogSci. Could you narrow down your question? As of now you're basically asking to provide you with a MatLab script. This is a scientific stack and we're not here to generate scripts for you. I'm putting this question on hold. Feel free to edit it if you have a more CogSci-related issue here. Good luck!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because CogSci is a scientific stack and I consider scripting offtopic here.